# Ad Control for XNA on WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, ads

Is it possible to show ads in XNA games on Windows Phone 7?

The MS ad control does not support XNA. There is a control for Admob on codeplex but that is Silverlight only.

Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MS has updated the control to support XNA! [More info](http://advertising.microsoft.com/mobile-apps).

Answer (score 2):

All the currently available Ad controls are all written in/for Silverlight.

Unfortunatley, for now you'll have to create your own way of displaying ads.